# Little $o$ relation

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Does $\log f(x)= o( \log g(x))$ imply $f(x)= o( g(x))$, where none of $f$ and $g$ is constant?

Here, $f(x)= o( g(x))$ means $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0.$
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Please include your attempts in the question body.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this hint. I think the relationship is between log f(x) and log g(x). I am not able to use your hint.@angryvian

Comment: You may find it easier to rephrase the question as: if $F(x) = o(G(x))$ then does $\exp(F(x)) = o(\exp(G(x))$?  Pay particular attention to the case where $G(x) \to 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x) = 1+\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x) = 2$ and so $ \log f(x) = o( \log g(x) )$

But $ \lim \limits_ { x \to \infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @mathisfun If your complaint is that $g$ is constant here, Ahmad's counterexample would also work with $g(x)=2+\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: @mathisfun You have edited the question in an inessential way that suggests you haven’t given any thought to the ramifications of this counterexample.  If your real goal is to identify sufficient conditions to make this true, then please state so, rather than moving the goalposts.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Thanks a lot everyone.